Must an entire function bounded on all vertical lines $Re(z) =c \neq 0$ also be bounded on $Re(z)=0$?
Let  $f(z)$ be an entire function (holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$) which satisfies the following property:

$ f(z) $ is bounded on every vertical line $\operatorname{Re}(z) = c$, for all $ c \neq 0 $.

Question: Does it follow that $ f(z) $ must also be bounded on the vertical line $ \operatorname{Re}(z) = 0 $?

Motivation
If we weaken the holomorphic assumption and only require that $f(x, y)$ (where $ z = x + i y $) be a smooth function of two variables, the function
$$
f(x, y) = y e^{-x^2 y^2}
$$
provides a counterexample. It is bounded on all vertical lines $x = c \neq 0 $, but it is not bounded on $ x = 0 $. Thus, the property likely hinges on the stronger condition of holomorphy.
This question is inspired by the "counterexample" to Phragmén-Lindelöf's theorem in the case of supra-exponential vertical growth within a strip. Specifically, consider the function
$$
f(z) = \exp\left(\exp\left(\frac{i \pi z}{2}\right)\right).
$$
This function is bounded on the vertical lines $\operatorname{Re}(z) = \pm 1 $, but it is unbounded on every line $ -1 < \operatorname{Re}(z) < 1 $. However, this example does not directly apply to the current question, as the growth inside the strip is supra-exponential, and the vertical growth conditions differ.

Thoughts
I suspect that holomorphy introduces constraints that might prevent the existence of a counterexample. However, I have been unable to prove the assertion or construct an explicit counterexample. Any insights, references, or hints would be greatly appreciated.

yes there are such functions and they are not that hard to construct using Cauchy integrals or even Taylor series and the Lindelof method of writing them as integrals in some cases - see the identical MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190837/entire-function-bounded-at-every-line for a few ways to do it (and of course rotate the examples there by $90$ degrees to move from horizontal behavior to vertical behavior)
